# Is it possible to fetch all data with population in mongoose with ID's?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a query in my API endpoint that fetches all documents and sub documents. Currently I have only had luck fetching the ID's of each sub document instead of fetching all of the information within each document. Is it possible to extract the data from each sub document based on each ID using mongoose(along with the data in the parent document)?

I have followed the documentation for deep populating: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate, but have not had much luck.

This is my current code that "works" but only responds with the ID's of each sub document(*and the User data which is fine*).

```
//The get request
router.get("/allUsers", async (req, res) => {
  const allUsers = await User.find()
    .populate("Post")
    .exec();
  res.send(allUsers);
});

//User Schema
const userSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }]
});

//Post Schema
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true }
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

What am I missing to extract ALL of the information from the sub documents instead of the ID alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JohnnyHK stated you need to use the name of the field to populate.

If you are having empty array of posts, please check  your users collection if you have a posts array with the post ids.

Here are the steps I could make it work:

1-) Inserted 2 posts like this to the posts collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc6cd65067a61191839ff38"),
    "name" : "name 3",
    "description" : "description 3",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-11-09T17:29:57.249+03:00")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc6cd5d067a61191839ff37"),
    "name" : "name 2",
    "description" : "description 2",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-11-09T17:29:49.070+03:00")
}
```

2-) Inserted a user with these 2 posts id.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc6cf5b67da8a40cc519866"),
    "posts" : [
        ObjectId("5dc6cd5d067a61191839ff37"),
        ObjectId("5dc6cd65067a61191839ff38")
    ],
    "name" : "user 1",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-11-09T17:38:19.807+03:00")
}
```

3-) And used the following route to get posts in user.

```
router.get("/allUsers", async (req, res) => {
  const allUsers = await User.find().populate("posts");

  res.send(allUsers);
});
```

The result is like this:

```
[
    {
        "posts": [
            {
                "_id": "5dc6cd5d067a61191839ff37",
                "name": "name 2",
                "description": "description 2",
                "date": "2019-11-09T14:29:49.070Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5dc6cd65067a61191839ff38",
                "name": "name 3",
                "description": "description 3",
                "date": "2019-11-09T14:29:57.249Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "5dc6cf5b67da8a40cc519866",
        "name": "user 1",
        "date": "2019-11-09T14:38:19.807Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

**By the way** your user and post modeling is not ideal. Every time user posts the user document must be updated.

I would use the following schemas (parent referencing).

User model ( I removed the posts field, and added virtual feature)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}, {
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

userSchema.virtual("posts", {
  ref: "Post",
  foreignField: "userId",
  localField: "_id"
})

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Post model ( I added the userId)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
});

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

With this way user document is not affected when a user posts. And you can use the same /allUsers  route to get users with their posts included.

Comment: Guessing I had another error somewhere else because this still did not work sadly. I ended up just using an array of Posts instead of only referencing the Id, but guessing that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the name of the field to `populate`, not the name of the model:

```
const allUsers = await User.find()
  .populate("posts")
  .exec();
```

Comment: That just returns an empty array of posts, why?

Comment: Turn on mongoose debugging to see what it's doing: `mongoose.set('debug', true);`

Answer (score 0):

use populate inside other populate

```
.populate({
      path: 'document',
      populate: { path: 'sub document'}
    })
```